# Splitting Multi Text in 2 different text boxes from 1 text box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a textbox with multi text enabled, I have some text data like this: 
[image]

How can I do this in Visual Basic?

I have setup a project like this, but it does for single line, but I want to make it multi line.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim somestring2() As String


    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        somestring2 = TextBox1.Text.Split(":")
        For i = 0 To somestring2.Length - 1
            For a = 0 To somestring2.Length - 2
                TextBox3.Text = somestring2(i)
                TextBox2.Text = somestring2(a)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox4.Text = TextBox2.Text + ":" + TextBox3.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        somestring2 = TextBox1.Text.Split(":")
        For i = 0 To somestring2.Length - 1
            For a = 0 To somestring2.Length - 2
                TextBox2.Text = somestring2(i)
                TextBox3.Text = somestring2(a)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox1.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Butto[`enter image description here`][1]n5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim fl As String
        ofd.ShowDialog()
        fl = ofd.FileName
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(fl)
        TextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where is the text sample?

Comment: in image above and it should be like this 
ddddd:aaaaaaaa
aaaaa:bbbbb
aaaaa:bbbbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.Split`, for example with this LINQ query:

```
Dim allLineSplits = From line In TextBox1.Lines
                    Let split = line.Split({"+"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    Where split.Length >= 2
                    Select split

Dim textBox2Lines = From split In allLineSplits
                    Select split(0).Trim()
Dim textBox3Lines = From split In allLineSplits
                    Select split(1).Trim()
TextBox2.Lines = textBox2Lines.ToArray()
TextBox3.Lines = textBox3Lines.ToArray()
```

If you want to combine both texts again in another TextBox, so get the same string that was before in `TextBox1`, you can use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
Dim allLines = From line In TextBox2.Lines.Zip(TextBox3.Lines,Function(l1, l2) New With{l1, l2}))
Dim textBox4Lines = From x in allLines Select $"{x.l1}+{x.l2}"
TextBo4.Lines = textBox4Lines.ToArray()
```

Note that `$"{x.l1}:{x.l2}"` is string interpolation what is new in VB14(VS 2015), if you can't use it use string concatenation or `String.Format`.

Comment: that worked perfect :D 
now how can i combine splitted lines in to textbox4 ?

Comment: How do you want to combine them for example?

Comment: i mean that splitted text is in textbox2 & textbox3 so i want those both result into textbox4 
mean to say i want to split those lines 1st then want to invert text lines then want to combine them again

Comment: How do you want to combine them **for example**? Do you want the same text as it originally was in TextBox1?

Comment: yup actually i want all the text in 
EX: textbox4 = textbox2.text + "+" + textbox3.tex

Comment: @AHM3D: actually you want all text that was originally in TextBox1 in TextBox4?

Comment: EX: textbox4 = textbox2.text + "+" + textbox3.text